# heroku h10 error ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, crash

I am trying to get an application I've developed with Ruby on Rails to work on Heroku. The application works perfectly fine when deployed locally; however, when I get it on Heroku I can not access it. I get an "application error" without further info.

Checking the logs I get only a few lines that do not shed much light on the matter:

```
2014-07-02T05:31:32.539488+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 25355 -e production` 
2014-07-02T05:31:38.355949+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-07-02T05:31:38.343493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-07-02T08:18:08.566516+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-07-02T08:18:12.335526+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 9061 -e production`
2014-07-02T08:18:17.276166+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-07-02T08:18:17.285370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-07-02T14:48:47.193171+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shielded-plateau-2387.herokuapp.com request_id=c9edd995-86c7-4487-b7de-8636d191d616 fwd="201.197.106.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-02T14:48:48.685921+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shielded-plateau-2387.herokuapp.com request_id=07195b7c-aa89-435a-a47c-c3ef5df5ed7e fwd="201.197.106.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I've been searching in this website and I've seen LOTS of similar posts, but in the other cases the logs show a syntax error, a missing gem or something that makes it a little easier to understand what is going on. Since these logs don't give that much information, I'm honestly stuck.

Sorry if this is trivial, I'm new at this platform.

Thank you beforehand.

Edit:

Using `heroku logs -t` after resetting the dynos I get the following:

```
2014-07-02T16:43:56.048188+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-07-02T16:44:00.765499+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 21115 -e production`
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234607+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234636+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234702+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234725+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234414+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234561+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234746+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234284+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Admins (NameError)
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234817+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234795+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235053+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235074+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234904+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234313+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234998+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235031+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234585+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234838+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234860+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.230035+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235321+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235183+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235428+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235096+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235218+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235247+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235279+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234926+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.234957+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235532+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235677+00:00 app[web.1]:   from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235596+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235501+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235553+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235574+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235155+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235124+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235300+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235342+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235375+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235472+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235450+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235655+00:00 app[web.1]:   from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.235624+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-07-02T16:44:14.226310+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-07-02T16:44:14.226333+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-07-02T16:44:14.226330+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-07-02T16:44:14.226327+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.1 application starting in production on `http://0.0.0.0:21115`
2014-07-02T16:44:14.226332+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-07-02T16:44:15.945215+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-07-02T16:44:15.958809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-07-02T16:44:17.241338+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shielded-plateau-2387.herokuapp.com request_id=7936ca94-2ff4-4f0f-83fd-4cd39d1b15db fwd="201.197.106.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-02T16:44:19.182713+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shielded-plateau-2387.herokuapp.com request_id=89c71d00-2b24-4c69-9c0b-187f961ad535 fwd="201.197.106.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: What do you get if you tail the logs (`heroku logs -t`) in one Terminal, and restart the app (`heroku ps:restart`) in another?

Comment: I have included the tally of the logs after resetting the dynos and trying Heroku once again. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: What's the content of `admin_controller.rb`?